# How to remove ANSI codes from a string?

Tags: lua

I am working on string manipulation using LUA and having trouble with the following problem.

Using this as an example of the original data I am given -

"[0;1;36m(Web): You say, "Text here."[0;37m"

I want to keep the string intact except for removing the ANSI codes.

I have been pointed toward using gsub with the LUA pattern matching but I cannot seem to get the pattern correct. I am also unsure how to reference exactly the escape character sent.

```
text:gsub("[\27\[([\d\;]+)m]", "")
or
text:gsub("%x%[[%d+;+]m", "")
```

If successful, all I want to be left with, using the above example, would be:

(Web): You say, "Text here."

Comment: What are "ANSI codes"?

Comment: @NicolBolas it looks like https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55321171/how-to-remove-ansi-codes-from-a-string

Answer (score 2):

Your string example is missing the escape character, ASCII 27.

Here's one way:

```
s = '\x1b[0;1;36m(Web): You say, "Text here."\x1b[0;37m'
s = s:gsub('\x1b%[%d+;%d+;%d+;%d+;%d+m','')
     :gsub('\x1b%[%d+;%d+;%d+;%d+m','')
     :gsub('\x1b%[%d+;%d+;%d+m','')
     :gsub('\x1b%[%d+;%d+m','')
     :gsub('\x1b%[%d+m','')
print(s)
```